# Regular expression and pattern matching to find elements of a list, not a string

Tags: r, list, pattern-matching

I am trying to do a simple task of pulling certain elements from a list, but the problem is that some of the element names have the same letters, but different numbers. Rather than type out all possible combinations, I want a way to use a wildcard to represent any number.

So here is part of the list I want to take elements from:

```
frame@description= $`$TOT`
[1] "100000"

$`$BEGINSTEXT`
[1] "0"

$`$ENDSTEXT`
[1] "0"

$`$NEXTDATA`
[1] "0"

$`$BEGINANALYSIS`
[1] "0"

$`$ENDANALYSIS`
[1] "0"

$`$BEGINDATA`
[1] "3851"

$`$ENDDATA`
[1] "24003850"

$`$P1N`
[1] "Time"

$`$P1B`
[1] "32"

$`$P1E`
[1] "0,0"

$`$P1R`
[1] "524288"

$`$P2N`
[1] "Event-length"

$`$P2B`
[1] "32"

$`$P2E`
[1] "0,0"

$`$P2R`
[1] "4096"

$`$P3N`
[1] "Y89Di"

$`$P3S`
[1] "89Y"

$`$P3B`
[1] "32"
```

Here is the vector of elements I want to pull:

```
requiredKeys = c("$BEGINANALYSIS","$BEGINDATA","$BEGINSTEXT","$BYTEORD","$DATATYPE","$ENDANALYSIS","$ENDDATA","$ENDSTEXT","$MODE","$NEXTDATA","$PAR","$P*B","$P*E","$P*N","$P*R","$TOT")
```

As you can see, there is `$P1N`, `$P2N`, `$P3N`, etc. in the LIST, which I want to represent this with `$P1*N` or `$P[0-9]N` in the VECTOR, but it doesn't work if I just type it that way.

If I type `frame@description[requiredKeys]`, I get all the elements I want, except for those that have the wildcard character.

I am wondering if there is a simple way to do this the way I have set it up, or if I will have to use grep, grepl or something like that.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's much easier to help if you post the results of `dput` on a representative sample of your data, since this is a question about data types

Comment: Try using `requiredKeys <- gsub("\\\\\\*", ".*", gsub("([]\\~!@#$%^&*(){}_<>?[|-])", "\\\\\\1", requiredKeys))` before `grep`ping.

Comment: `frame@description[grep(paste0(gsub("\\*", "\\.*", gsub("\\$", "\\\\$", requiredKeys)), collapse="|"), names(alist), value=TRUE)]`